# Launching Azure debug from Visual studio and bind in * instead of 127.0.0.1

Tags: azure

I am doing a small app using Windows Azure.

While debugging my app and I wanted to make a request from another computer and I couldn't get to it. Although I can see the IIS webpage.

Looking into netstat I found this:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             Windows7-VBox:0        LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:81           Windows7-VBox:0        LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:82           Windows7-VBox:0        LISTENING
```

How can I make Azure bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1?

EDIT:
Here's a good [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/9b8957e6-7983-47a7-9d75-954dee70dbf0) with the different options available.
Looks like http://www.iis.net/expand/ApplicationRequestRouting is the simple thing to do but I can't manage to get it working.

The rule is up and running but when I hit it from the other computer I just see a browser of files. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for security reasons. (WA Simulation Environment runs elevated.)

But if you grab a port forwarder, you can probably rig something up.